# Android app freezes before cursor.movetofirst no error is shown

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have this app that is querying an sqlite database, im reusing code to fetch data and it's working for 10+ queries but this one query is freezing my app right before corsor.movetonext

The query is working when i run it through SQLite Database browser with the same database as on my phone.

This is my query:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>hml = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
String fetchdata="select Gest.Dep,time(Gest.Dep,'unixepoch') as DTE,mobileAT.db_desp,Rock.RockNo,Travel.TravelNo,RockTravel.TravelSequence,Turn.Line,Turn.Description,Gest.StopSequence,Gest.Arrival,TurnStop.HaltId,Stop.Description,Stop.StopNo,CAST(LinkDot.Latitude as REAL)/1000000 as Lat,CAST(LinkDot.Longitude as REAL)/1000000 as Lng from Cal\n" +
                "      \n" +
                "                inner join Rock on Rock.TimetableVersion=Cal.TimetableVersion\n" +
                "                inner join RockTravel on Rock.Id=RockTravel.RockId\n" +
                "                inner join Travel on Travel.TimetableVersion=Cal.TimetableVersion and Travel.Id=RockTravel.TravelId\n" +
                "                inner join Turn on Travel.TurnId= Turn.Id\n" +
                "                inner join LinkDot on Stop.Id = LinkDot.FromHaltId\n" +
                "                inner join Gest on Gest.TravelId=RockTravel.TravelId\n" +
                "                inner join TurnStop on TurnStop.TurnId=Turn.Id  and TurnStop.StopSequence=Gest.StopSequence\n" +
                "                inner join Stop on Stop.Id=TurnStop.HaltId\n" +
                "                inner join mobileAT on mobileAT.db_desp=\""+desp+"\"\n" +
                "                \n" +
                "where Rock.RockNo=mobileAT.db_way  and LinkDot.Distance=0 and LinkDot.ToHaltId=-1 and time(Gest.Dep,'unixepoch') between mobileAT.db_time_from and mobileAT.db_time_to\n" +
                "group by Gest.Dep order by Gest.Dep"

SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(fetchdata, null);

        Log.d("MSG","outside loop");

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do
            {

Log.d("MSG","inside loop");

                HashMap<String, String> Hmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
                Hmap.put("1",cursor.getString(0));
                Hmap.put("2",cursor.getString(1));
                Hmap.put("3",cursor.getString(2));
                Hmap.put("4",cursor.getString(3));
                Hmap.put("5",cursor.getString(4));
                Hmap.put("6",cursor.getString(5));
                Hmap.put("7",cursor.getString(6));
                Hmap.put("8",cursor.getString(7));
                hml.add(Hmap);

} while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }else{
            Log.d("MSG","here atleast?");
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d("MSG","Im leaving");
        return hml;
```

I am getting the Log.d("MSG","outside loop") LOG but nothing else and i can not understand what is causing the freeze.

Comment: why do you use do...while loop?

Comment: Im just trying to add all my result rows to my ArrayList. What would you suggest i use instead? It's working for all other queries i've made with this code. @pskink

Comment: you need it for ArrayAdapter?

Comment: This is not an infinite freeze; your query is just too slow (especially with the old SQLite version and the weak CPU on that device).

Comment: @CL you are right, the query is quite slow, it takes 2394ms on my not to fast laptop, Im developing on xperia Z with Quad-core 1.5 GHz Krait CPU and left the app for several minutes, nothing... I have another query that takes ~1100ms on the laptop and it opens in about 10 seconds on the phone

Comment: @pskink Yes im adding the results to a ListView

Comment: Show the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output for this query.

Comment: so use SimpleCursorAdapter,  not ArrayAdapter,  why to make it complex?

Comment: @CL you where right, i ran a less taxing version on the phone and i finished in 45 seconds, i also added "Show CPU usage layer" to my phone screen and the cpu is really trying hard.. :) I guess i have to rethink this, thank you all.

Comment: Did you index your key fields? Try to do that, and gain a boost of several hundreds percent!

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a much simpler query. I don't think that performance is the issue in my case. My query runs "instantaneously" in adb. No other query (all are as complex as this one) is causing this issue. Any idea?